# Strange behaviour using roman pagenumbering

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am using `pagenumbering{roman}` for my titlepage tables and `pagenumbering{arabic}` for the rest. My problem is, that the part with roman numbering behaves strange, I try to explain it as follows:

```
first page/titlepage: no numbering
second page:          i
third page:           no numbering
fourth page:          iii
fifth page:           no numbering
sixth page:           v
seventh page:         no numbering
eighth page:          no numbering
ninth page:           viii
```

What I would like is an uninterrupted numbering from i to viii.

Can someone help me with that?

P.S.: This is a shortened version of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew,latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{margin=3cm}
\centering

Some text

\end{titlepage}


\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\newpage
more text
\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\pagestyle{plain}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
main document


:
:
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your preamble? It's hard to say what to do without knowing a little more.

Comment: It's normal in books to not put the page numbers on some pages so there is probably nothing strange with this. If you want to change it there is probably not problem in changing it either, but then you must tell us how you have done this.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which shows your basic set up and demonstrates the issue. Then people will be able to suggest how you can adapt your code to include numbers even on pages they are usually omitted from.

Comment: I have added my preamble

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty}` suppresses the page number. The MWE only generates *three* instead of eight or nine (also not clear) pages. `\newgeometry` is not known, if package `geometry` is not loaded.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Hello Heiko, I have just modified my code. Now you can see the probelm.

Comment: Ok, I removed the `\pagestyle{empty}` now it works... Thanks!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek An answer?

Comment: @egreg: Answer written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility of the page numbers can be explained the following way:

- Page 1: `\thispagestyle{empty}` by `\begin{titlepage}`
- Page 2: `\thispagestyle{plain}` by `\chapter*` of `\tableofcontents`
- Pages 3 to 8: `\pagestyle{empty}` right after `\begin{document}`
- Page 9: `\pagestyle{plain}` right before `\clearpage`

Page style `empty` means, the page number is not visible.

Also both `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepage}` resets the page counter to one.

Thus the example can be fixed by using `\pagestyle{plain}` instead of `\pagestyle{empty}` and patching environment `titlepage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\titlepage{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}
  {}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\titlepage}}
\patchcmd\titlepage{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}
  {}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\titlepage}}
\patchcmd\endtitlepage{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}
  {}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\endtitlepage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

Some text

\end{titlepage}


\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\newpage
more text
\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\pagestyle{plain}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
main document 
\end{document}
```

Alternatively of patching environment `titlepage` the page style and page number can be manually set:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\centering

Some text

\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\newpage
more text
\newpage 
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\newpage
some more text

\pagestyle{plain}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
main document
\end{document}
```