# Page numbering problem after title page

Tags: numbering

I am writing thesis. The problem is the page numbering after title page. It should be page number (ii) on Abstract. Instead it's page number (i). here is the code

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{Chapters/titlepage}
\chapter{Abstract}
\input{Chapters/Abstract}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\input{Chapters/Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Point to Point Comm}
\input{Chapters/chapter01}
\chapter{Massive}
\input{Chapters/chapter02}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{Chapters/chapter03}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's in the files `titlepage.tex` and `Abstract.tex`?

Comment: The titlepage.tex contains the title which begins and ends like this, \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}  
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}. Abstract.tex contains only text.

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208/37907)

Comment: Don't use the `titlepage` environment. Use a simple `\thispagestyle{empty}` for the titlepage instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour using roman pagenumbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180266/strange-behaviour-using-roman-pagenumbering)